# How to export the data to the database from Analysis services in Extended Events automatically

Tags: ssis, ssas

> I created a session in extended events for tracking of Tabular. I need
>   to export the extended events data to the database automatically.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to understand how to post a good question so that the community can assist you. Please edit your post and add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any errors or logs you might get.